# How do I link two HTML files present on the same server?

Tags: html, server, hosting

I have signed up on infinityfree.net and uploaded my files online in the folder which said "upload yours files here".

Now there are two HTMLs present in the folder namely

1. Index2.html
2. chatbox.html

I want to link an chat box to an image in the index file I used all proper tags(I know because I tried https://www.google.com and it worked), but I'm just not able to do it.

Things I tried:

1. "https://www.domain-name.cf/chatbox.html"
2. "chatbox.html"
3. "/htdocs/chatbox.html"(htdocs is the name of the folder)

I also got the errors `404` and `403`.
Please help.

Comment: Not sure how we can help without being able to see your HTML...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using PHP you can use the `header("Location:path_to_your_file");`

Answer (score 1):

I realized that infinityfree prevents accessing files which contains "chat" in their names , try to rename chatbox.html with another name who doesn't contain "chat" then it will work for sure .

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="chatbox.html"><img>...</img></a>
```

This should work for you.

Since both the files are in same folder you can directly write "chatbox.html".

Comment: then i get this Error:::::403 Forbidden

The website's configuration prevents you from accessing this page.

Comment: It's because you don't have permission to access chatbox.html. Go to the chatbox.html location in htdocs folder and there try to change permission to "rw-r--r--" or create a new file and copy/paste the code from chatbox.html to new file(Creating new file automatically takes care of required permisiion to access file)

Comment: the File "chatbox.html" already has its permissions set to "rw-r--r--", then Again I tried creating a new file, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Try to load chatbox.html in your web browser " https://www.domain-name.cf/chatbox.html " and see if the chatbox.html page loads up or shows the same error

Comment: sorry for the late reply, when I do that I get a 404 error.